# Best Way to Build & Design Buttons for iOS in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, mobile

I have been getting into designing interfaces for iOS, mostly iPhone and iPhone 4 retina display. I'm wondering how I should go about creating interfaces, the most standard way? I have been using the [iPhone 4 GUI PSD](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/) which helps a lot. But I'm really interested to create my own buttons, and scale them easily into @2x sizes.

Some great examples of apps that use custom buttons are Instagram, Foursquare, Gowalla, and Tweetbot to name just a few. Ideally I'd like to stick with Photoshop since I'm most comfortable with the tools and layout. I haven't worked with vector graphics a lot, but I'm willing to give it a try if scaling for @2x is easier. But I'd love to hear any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out MediaLoot's blog here: http://medialoot.com/item/iphone-app-icon-kit/ The kit shows you layer-by-layer how to create iPhone/iPad app icons. You can download it free, but then they request you mention them in any commercial application if you use it. If you subscribe, they drop that request.

The team there creates awesome web graphics, with many detailed free tutorials in their blog. FYI, I subscribe.

Comment: thanks I do appreciate it, but I'm more looking for iOS layouts/buttons/UI elements. not exactly how to design an iOS app icon, which is what the article focuses on.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I focused on this: "But I'm really interested to create my own buttons, and scale them easily into @2x sizes."